# Php Update using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to build a custom class to manage operations with database. I'm a beginner with OOP so if you have any suggests please tell me. By the way, i have an update method which took as parameter the name of the table, the fields to update, the values with which i want to update the fields and the fields and values to put in where clause of query.
At this time, i have two distinct arrays, one for the set part and one for the where part. 
I build the query string like so `PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => UPDATE Ordini SET Nome=':Nome', Cognome=': Cognome', Telefono=': Telefono' WHERE ID=':ID' )`

Now i would like to bind the params to the variables and execute the query and that's the problem. I try this way but the query don't update the fields.
- In $values i have the values i want to bind to variables in the SET part
- In $wv i have the values i want to bind to variables in the WHERE part
- In $fieldsQuery i have the placeholders for the SET part(":Nome" for example)
- In $fieldsWhere i have the placeholders for the WHERE part

How can i bind in the right way the placeholders with the variables?

```
public function update($table=NULL, $fieldsQuery=NULL, $fieldsValues = NULL, $whereFields=NULL, $whereValues=NULL, $whereOperators = NULL)
{
    if($fieldsQuery != NULL)
        $fields = explode(",", $fieldsQuery);
    if($fieldsValues != NULL)
        $values = explode(",", $fieldsValues);
    if($whereFields != NULL)
        $wf = explode(",", $whereFields);
    if($whereValues != NULL)
        $wv = explode(",", $whereValues);

    $fieldsQuery = array_map(function($field) { return ":$field";}, $fields);
    $bindValuesSet = array_combine($fieldsQuery, $values);
    //return an array in which every field is => Fieldname=':Fieldname' 
    $bindSetInitial = array_combine($fields, $fieldsQuery);


    //transform every item in array from field to :field
    $fieldsWhere = array_map(function($field) { return ":$field";}, $wf);
    $bindValuesWhere = array_combine($fieldsWhere, $wv);
    $bindWhereInitial = array_combine($wf, $fieldsWhere);

    //implode an array mantaining both key and value
    $fieldsValues = implode(', ', array_map(function ($v, $k) { return sprintf("%s='%s'", $k, $v); }, $bindSetInitial, array_keys($bindSetInitial)));
    $fieldsWhere = implode(', ', array_map(function ($v, $k) { return sprintf("%s='%s'", $k, $v); }, $bindWhereInitial, array_keys($bindWhereInitial)));

    $query = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE ' . $table . ' SET ' . $fieldsValues . ' WHERE ' . $fieldsWhere);

    $query->bindParam(':Nome', $values[0]);
    $query->bindParam(':Cognome', $values[1]);
    $query->bindParam(':Telefono', $values[2]);
    $query->bindParam(':ID', $wv[0], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $query->execute();
    print_r($query->debugDumpParams());
}
```

Comment: there shouldn't be any quotes in `': Cognome'` etc. and there is a space in there etc.. check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: I suspect the space in `implode(', ',` and the quotes in `return sprintf("%s='%s'",` - you need to remove them.

Comment: First, thank you for the help! I removed the quotes. Now the query string looks like this UPDATE Ordini SET Nome=:Nome, Cognome=: Cognome, Telefono=: Telefono WHERE ID=:ID. I'm searching for the space problem

Comment: prego. Spaces are being added somewhere in your build and I suspect in `implode(', ',` so try `implode(',',` in both

Comment: Spaces appear with `explode`, not `implode`. Exploding `'Nome, Cognome'` by `,` gives you `Nome` and `[space]Cognome`.

Comment: @DorinoCanciani where are we with this? any comments here lead to a solution?

Comment: Yes as you suggest i remove quotes and after that i remove whitespace. Then i have to do some stuff to bind value and now it works but it's only a base structure because i want to improve it. Do i make a post with the solution?

Comment: @DorinoCanciani if my comments were the solution, let me know and I will post it as answer to close the question. @ me

Comment: @Fred sorry for late answer. Yes that helps me to solve the problem :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

`':Nome'` is not a placeholder for a prepared statement. It's just a string `':Nome'`

Placeholder is `:Nome` (without `) and without any spaces, tabs etc.
I.e. `: Nome` is **not a placeholder** too.

So, you query should be:

```
UPDATE Ordini SET Nome=:Nome, Cognome=:Cognome, Telefono=:Telefono WHERE ID=:ID
```

And thanks to @Fred-ii- - read [error handling section of PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: sure, but that doesn't fix the problem. The issue is in their build where the quotes and spaces are being added somehow and I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Here `sprintf("%s='%s'", $k, $v)` I suppose. And spaces come from `explode`. `trim` is not our friend.

Comment: I said that in a comment under their question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed that and some other stuff and it works! Now i'm going to improve it!